# Hatching an egg - distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The time for an egg to hatch distributes exponentially with expected value of $15$. What is the probability for the egg to not hatch after $10$ days?

So Can I say it's $1$ minus the probability for hatch in the 10th day? And just put it in the distribution PDF formula with $\lambda = 1/15$ and $x = 10$?

Comment: egg-cellent solution.